# how will I access the methods into my Switch statement?

Tags: c#

how do I access the methods??

- how do I access the methods??
- and use them in Switch statement?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace practise_Delegates_MenuDriven
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate int Converter(int value);

        static int ToCel(int fah)
        {
            return fah;
        }
        static int  ToFah(int celsius)
        {
            return celsius;
        }
        static int ToKel(int celsius2)
        {
            return celsius2;
        }
        static int ToRank(int celsius3)
        {
            return celsius3;
        }
        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Celsius Converter");
            Console.WriteLine("=================");
            Console.WriteLine("C - Celsius to Fahrenheit");
            Console.WriteLine("F - Fahrenheit to Celsius");
            Console.WriteLine("K - Celsius to Kelvin");
            Console.WriteLine("R - Celsius to Rankine");
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");

        }
        static char GetMenuOption(char letter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter C, F, K, R, X: ");
            letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            return letter;
        }
        static int GetValue(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value to convert: ");
            value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return value;
        }
        static void PrintResult(int fromValue,int result,string fromstring,string toString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fromValue + " " + fromstring + " is " + result + " " + toString);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Converter process =  ToCel;
            Converter process1 = ToCel;
            Converter process2 = ToKel;
            Converter process3 = ToKel;

          ***switch statement? while loop?***
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: This is about the most basic thing you can do with a program, this a not a school and its not about answering trivial programming questions. as it stands you haven't done any research on a switch statement, and just want it solved for you. therefor this should be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need arguments in GetMenuOption() and GetValue() methods. And here is loop (it is needed if you want to process more than one temperature) with switch:

```
while (true)
{
    DisplayMenu();
    var letter = GetMenuOption();
    var fromString = String.Empty;
    var toString = String.Empty;

    if (letter == 'X')
    {
        break;
    }

    var fromValue = GetValue();
    var result = 0;

    switch (letter)
    {
        case 'C':
            fromString = "F";
            toString = "C";
            result = process(fromValue);
            break;
        case 'F':
            fromString = "C";
            toString = "F";
            result = process1(fromValue);
            break;
        case 'K':
            fromString = "C";
            toString = "K";
            result = process2(fromValue);
            break;
        case 'R':
            fromString = "C";
            toString = "R";
            result = process3(fromValue);
            break;
    }

    PrintResult(fromValue, result, fromString, toString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (charValue) {
    case 'C':
        ToCel(int val);
        break;
    case 'F':
        ToFah(int val);
        break;
    //rest of the case
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("invalid value");
        break;
}
```

You need to pass the character input into the switch statement, then you can decide what to do for each different case.

also, why are you passing a char and an int into `GetMenuOption` and `GetValue`?

it should be like this, unless you have a good reason

```
static char GetMenuOption()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter C, F, K, R, X: ");
    char letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    return letter;
}
static int GetValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value to convert: ");
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    return value;
}
```